# why lock camera when Mediarecorder is released

Tags: android, camera, mediarecorder

I don't know why camera object should be locked, since MediaRecorder object is released.
Here's the code:

```
    private void releaseMediaRecorder(){
        if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
            mMediaRecorder.reset();   // clear recorder configuration
            mMediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
            mMediaRecorder = null;
            mCamera.lock();           // lock camera for later use
//
        }
    }
```

The result of the function are
1.camera is locked, so it can not be used to take photo or by other application?
2.if this application is paused, stopped or destroyed, camera is unlocked automatically?

This is the standard code from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#release-camera

Comment: what exactly are you asking?

Comment: Title is what I want to ask.And are The results of mCamera.lock() right?

Answer (score 0):

If we see mCamera.lock(); is called in releaseMediaRecorder() method. The releaseMediaRecorder(); is called in onPause() method along with releaseCamera();.so, by seeing this you can understand that in releaseMediaRecorder() method media elements are enabled but the instance of the camera is created in releaseCamera() method till the instance is created our application should not use (or) cannot use the camera. That is why it is kept locked there and in releaseCamera() method if instance is not equal to null they release it.